# Postgres: Como comparar json para criar trigger de auditoria e exibir apenas as diferenças

Tags: postgresql, trigger, plpgsql

Conforme a estrutura abaixo, gostaria que quando fosse update eu conseguisse memorizar apenas as diferenças. Exemplo na tabela `produto` eu tenho os campos:

```
prodcodigo = 1
proddescricao = 'FILTRO DE OLEO'
prodestoque = 33
```

Se eu faço um update mudando o estoque pra 32 eu gostaria que na coluna diferença da minha tabela auditoria saísse somente o estoque que mudou.
Hoje o antes fica assim:

```
ANTES: {"prodcodigo":1,"proddescricao":"FILTRO DE OLEO","prodestoque":33}
DEPOIS: {"prodcodigo":1,"proddescricao":"FILTRO DE OLEO","prodestoque ":32}
DIFERENÇA: {"prodestoque ":33} > {"prodestoque ":32}
```

--TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE auditoria
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  operacao character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  data timestamp with time zone,
  usuario character varying(50),
  tabela character varying(50),
  antes text,
  depois text,
  diferenca text,
  CONSTRAINT auditoria_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

--TRIGGER FUNCTION

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auditoria() RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN 
        INSERT INTO auditoria(operacao, data, usuario, tabela, antes, depois, diferenca)
        VALUES (TG_OP, now(), user, TG_TABLE_NAME, '', row_to_json(NEW), '');   
    END IF;
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN 
        INSERT INTO auditoria(operacao, data, usuario, tabela, antes, depois, diferenca)
        VALUES (TG_OP, now(), user, TG_TABLE_NAME, row_to_json(OLD), row_to_json(NEW), '');     
    END IF;
    IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN 
        INSERT INTO auditoria(operacao, data, usuario, tabela, antes, depois, diferenca)
        VALUES (TG_OP, now(), user, TG_TABLE_NAME, row_to_json(OLD), '', '');       
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

-- TRIGGER

```
CREATE TRIGGER audit AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON prod FOR EACH ROW  EXECUTE PROCEDURE auditoria();
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que a utilização da trigger seria genérica para várias tabelas, nesse caso acredito ser interessante ter uma função para comparar os json com os registros. Dessa maneira você pode ir evoluindo a função de comparação independente da função de trigger.

Criei um exemplo utilizando o `postgres` 10 e os recursos do tipo de dado `jsonb`, sendo assim, alterei o tipo de dados de algumas colunas da tabela `auditoria` de `text` para `jsonb`.

```
CREATE TABLE auditoria
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    operacao character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    data timestamp with time zone,
    usuario character varying(50),
    tabela character varying(50),
    antes jsonb,
    depois jsonb,
    diferenca jsonb,
    CONSTRAINT auditoria_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table produto (
    codigo integer,
    descricao text,
    estoque numeric
);

insert into produto(codigo, descricao, estoque)
values(1, 'Filtro de óleo', 53), (2, 'Cerveja 600ml', 100);
```

A função abaixo recebe dois `jsonb`, que seriam os registros antigos e os novos respectivamente. Depois é feito um loop nas chaves do json que seriam os campos da tabela. Se na comparação dos dois objetos houver diferença ele retorna um novo json.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION fn_compara_jsonb(antigo jsonb, novo jsonb)
RETURNS jsonb
LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE STRICT
AS $function$
declare
    keys record;
    jsonb_retorno jsonb = '{}'::jsonb;
begin
    for keys in
        select *
        from jsonb_object_keys($1)
    loop
        if $1 -> keys.jsonb_object_keys <> $2 -> keys.jsonb_object_keys then
            jsonb_retorno = jsonb_retorno || format('{"%s": "old: %s, new: %s"}', keys.jsonb_object_keys, $1 ->> keys.jsonb_object_keys, $2 ->> keys.jsonb_object_keys)::jsonb;
        end if;
    end loop;
    return jsonb_retorno;
end
$function$;
```

Por fim a função acima é adicionada na função de trigger na seção correspondente ao campo `diferenca` seguindo a mesma lógica porem com algumas modificações para utilização do tipo `jsonb`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auditoria() RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN 
        INSERT INTO auditoria(operacao, data, usuario, tabela, antes, depois, diferenca)
        VALUES (TG_OP, now(), user, TG_TABLE_NAME, '{}'::jsonb, row_to_json(NEW.*), '{}'::jsonb);   
    END IF;
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN 
        INSERT INTO auditoria(operacao, data, usuario, tabela, antes, depois, diferenca)
        VALUES (TG_OP, now(), user, TG_TABLE_NAME, row_to_json(OLD.*), row_to_json(NEW.*), fn_compara_jsonb(to_jsonb(row_to_json(OLD.*)), to_jsonb(row_to_json(NEW.*))));     
    END IF;
    IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN 
        INSERT INTO auditoria(operacao, data, usuario, tabela, antes, depois, diferenca)
        VALUES (TG_OP, now(), user, TG_TABLE_NAME, row_to_json(OLD.*), '{}'::jsonb, '{}'::jsonb);       
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;

CREATE TRIGGER audit AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON produto FOR EACH ROW  EXECUTE PROCEDURE auditoria();
```

Após a atualização dos registros com um SQL semelhante a: `update produto set estoque=estoque+2;`, seriam gerados os registros na tabela `auditoria` conforme abaixo:

```
stackoverflow=# select * from auditoria where operacao='UPDATE';
┌─[ RECORD 1 ]────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ id        │ 10                                                          │
│ operacao  │ UPDATE                                                      │
│ data      │ 2018-10-01 21:18:14.928847-03                               │
│ usuario   │ postgres                                                    │
│ tabela    │ produto                                                     │
│ antes     │ {"codigo": 1, "estoque": 53, "descricao": "Filtro de óleo"} │
│ depois    │ {"codigo": 1, "estoque": 55, "descricao": "Filtro de óleo"} │
│ diferenca │ {"estoque": "old: 53, new: 55"}                             │
├─[ RECORD 2 ]────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ id        │ 11                                                          │
│ operacao  │ UPDATE                                                      │
│ data      │ 2018-10-01 21:18:14.928847-03                               │
│ usuario   │ postgres                                                    │
│ tabela    │ produto                                                     │
│ antes     │ {"codigo": 2, "estoque": 100, "descricao": "Cerveja 600ml"} │
│ depois    │ {"codigo": 2, "estoque": 102, "descricao": "Cerveja 600ml"} │
│ diferenca │ {"estoque": "old: 100, new: 102"}                           │
└───────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Tempo: 1,150 ms
```

A função `fn_compara_jsonb()` pode ser evoluída para de acordo o tipo dos dados retornar informações da comparação (maior que, menor que, etc).

Outra sugestão seria a tabela `auditoria` possuir apenas um campo jsonb com nome `modificacoes`, por exemplo, e na função `auditoria()` tratar como os dados seriam inseridos conforme cada operação (INSERT, UPDATE ou DELETE).

Espero que eu tenha conseguido dar uma direção para você resolver o seu problema :)

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver o problema de uma forma um pouco diferente que no meu ver ficou boa para o resultado que eu queria.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auditoria() RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    pCodigo integer;
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN 
        INSERT INTO auditoria(operacao, data, usuario, tabela, antes, depois, diferenca)
        VALUES (TG_OP, now(), user, TG_TABLE_NAME, '', row_to_json(NEW), '');   
    END IF;
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN 
        INSERT INTO auditoria(operacao, data, usuario, tabela, antes, depois, diferenca)
        VALUES (TG_OP, now(), user, TG_TABLE_NAME, row_to_json(OLD), row_to_json(NEW), '') RETURNING ID INTO pCodigo;

        UPDATE auditoria SET diferenca = (  SELECT string_agg(a || ' >> ' || b, ',') FROM (
                                            SELECT 
                                            CAST(json_each(antes::json) AS CHARACTER VARYING) AS a, CAST(json_each(depois::json) AS CHARACTER VARYING) AS b
                                            FROM auditoria WHERE id = pCodigo 
                                            ) AS T
                                            WHERE a <> b) WHERE id = pCodigo; 
    END IF;
    IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN 
        INSERT INTO auditoria(operacao, data, usuario, tabela, antes, depois, diferenca)
        VALUES (TG_OP, now(), user, TG_TABLE_NAME, row_to_json(OLD), '', '');       
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Desse jeito com o update consigo pegar as diferenças e vale para todas as tabelas